# Show only the last X months of a plotted line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I built a signal line that I would like to show on the chart for a limited period of time (say, last 12 months). The script should not display anything before that time.

I am using the code below to instruct the script when to start the signal line processing. To simplify things, in this example it will just increment a variable (`n`) and show that on the chart.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to hide the plotted line that shows **before** this last year period. Its value is zero, but that zero gets displayed on the chart too, and I would like to hide it. The line should only show an incrementing number in the last year.

Yes, I know about the `show_last` option for the `plot` instruction, but I could not find a way to link that variable to the number of bars that show this rising line, especially considering the multiple timeframes (daily, weekly and monthly).

So, when you run this script, you will see at the start of the chart a long horizontal line with a value of zero, and in the last 12 months you will see it rising with each bar. I would like to hide the first part (the zero part), and display it when it is rising. That's it!

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you!

Alex

```
//@version=5
indicator('My script')

var months_to_process = 12

var start = 0
var n = 0

date = time >= timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow) - months_to_process, 0, 0, 0, 0)
if (not date[1] and date)
    start := 1

if (start == 1)
    n := n + 1
    // signal line processing code goes here

plot (n, color=#000000, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `na` to `n` variable at first, and than change `na` to 0 only for the calculation if the condition is met using `nz()` function:

```
//@version=5
indicator('My script')

var months_to_process = 12

var start = 0
var int n = na 

date = time >= timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow) - months_to_process, 0, 0, 0, 0)
if (not date[1] and date)
    start := 1

if (start == 1)
    n := nz(n) + 1
    // signal line processing code goes here

plot (n, color=#000000, linewidth=2)
```